# Sencha Touch 2 : how to list data inside a scrollable panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to build a layout for my **Sencha Touch 2.4** app. 
I want a page with :

- a panel
- a list of data
- another panel

And i want a global scroll. I don't want to get a scroll on the list itself. The list should take all the height it needs to contains all data.

I created a fiddle for that : [here it is](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kl3). 
To see my problem, reduce the height of your brower window. All items are not visible anymore.
If you replace `flex:1` by `height:'400px'`, you will see what i try to obtain.

I tryed to set this size of the list when the `painted` event is triggered, with something like this :

```
   listeners: {
    painted: function() {
        this.setHeight(this.itemsCount*(this.getItemHeight()+3));
    }
```

but `getItemHeight` return a size that doesn't match the real size of each element.
Is there a clean way to get what i'm trying to achieve ?

Comment: So do you want to be able to scroll the entire panel containing the two panels and list AND be able to scroll the list of items?

Comment: I don't need a scroll on the list. I want the scroll on the entire panel, the one containing all the stuff. I finally succeed by putting my 2 extra panels into the list with scrollDock and docked attributes, but that's not perfect for my needs, and not logic.